# Performance issue of selecting two date columns as one field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two dates in my table

```
StartDate              EndDate     
-------                ---------
2015-07-29 03:58:43    2015-07-30 03:55:56.000
```

I want to display these two columns as one field like this:

```
2015-07-29 - 2015-07-30
```

I wrote this query but the problem is query is slow:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartDate , 111) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EndDate, 111))
FROM table
```

I'm looking for another query that improves performance. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when do this in client side application

Comment: Define slow.  Usually the operations in the SELECT block have very little impact on performance.  JOINs are where most of the cost occurs.  Your example query has no visible JOINs or WHERE clause, so you're scanning the entire table.

Comment: My query in comparison with `SELECT StartDate , EndDate FROM table` is slower because I have to fetch lots of data. I just looking for better way to do that if another solution exist. and of course in my main query JOIN and Where clause are available @MatBailie.

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT should not be much slower because of this calculation. You could however speed it up a bit by making a PERSISTED computed column. Downside is the extra space used by the table:

```
ALTER TABLE <yourtable> 
  ADD NewColumn as CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartDate , 111) + ' - ' +
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EndDate, 111) PERSISTED
```